# SVG colors rendered differently in FF/Chrome vs Safari

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg, safari

I have a few SVGs that I've exported from Sketch and that looks perfectly fine in the folder. But once I placed it in Firefox/Chrome, the color of the image embedded in the SVG suddenly turns lighter. Just to be sure, I tried opening the same files in Safari, and the colors are rendered perfectly. Does anyone know what's causing such discrepancies? Including [the link to the SVG code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Uebyn/portfolio/master/dist/img/templating.svg) and the screenshots of the SVG on Safari and Firefox respectively.

Thanks all in advance.

[image: SVG image on Safari]

[image]

Comment: The SVG looks like the second image for me in Firefox (and Chrome) on Win7.  I suspect this might be due to colour map tables in the PNG. Perhaps Mac FF is not using them?

Comment: I just opened the image on Win7 (virtualbox) with FF/Chrome/IE10, and they all look like the second image. Meaning Safari is the only one that renders the colors correctly? Hard to believe.

Comment: I'm confused. You state in your question that Safari is the second image.

Comment: My mistake - Safari is the one that renders the color correctly and the others render the colors lighter. Made the correction.

Comment: There is something going on with the PNG. I loaded it into Photoshop and resaved it and now it "works" in Chrome and FF.  Try that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I don't have Photoshop and resaving the PNG with Pixelmator didn't change anything, but it did get me thinking about the way Safari renders color profile differently from other browsers. After some testing, I finally decided to try exporting the original image to data URI format, then replacing the value in the SVG to this new value, and voila - it now works. Apparently Sketch exports PNG with the wrong colors. Thanks once again @PaulLeBeau.

Comment: The link to the SVG in your question is missing (as of December 1, 2017).